# Can't implement autoplay EmblaCarousel

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, autoplay, embla-carousel

I have a webpage built with Next.js,TypeScript and tailwindCSS. On this page, i want to show a bunch of cards, each representing a different animal. These cards have various attributes like images and items associated with them.

To manage the layout and functionality, i am using a carousel library called Embla Carousel. It's like a rotating display stand where you can showcase your cards one by one.

To make things interesting,i've added an autoplay feature to the carousel but didn't work, or I don't see why.

this is my page with carousel

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'; import { Cards } from '@/components/Cards/cards-row'; import littleAnimals from '../data/little-animals.json'; import HeaderAnimals from '@/components/Cards/header-Animalitos'; import  useEmblaCarousel from 'embla-carousel-react'; import Autoplay from 'embla-carousel-autoplay';   export function useWindowSize() {   const isClient = typeof window === 'object';    const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState({     width: isClient ? window.innerWidth : undefined,     height: isClient ? window.innerHeight : undefined,   });    useEffect(() => {     function handleResize() {       setWindowSize({         width: window.innerWidth,         height: window.innerHeight,       });     }      window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);      return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);   }, []);    return windowSize; }  const LittleAnimals: React.FC = () => {   const windowSize = useWindowSize();   const [emblaRef, emblaApi] = useEmblaCarousel({ loop: true, axis: 'y' }, [     Autoplay({       delay: 10000,     }),   ]);   console.log(emblaRef);   console.log(emblaApi);   console.log(Autoplay);    useEffect(() => {     if (emblaApi) {       if ((windowSize.width ?? 0) <= 846) {         // sm and md sizes         emblaApi.reInit({ loop: false, axis: 'y', slidesToScroll: 1 });       } else {         emblaApi.reInit({ loop: true, axis: 'y', slidesToScroll: 4 });       }     }   }, [emblaApi, windowSize]);    const divideArray = <T,>(array: T[], chunkSize: number): T[][] => {     if (chunkSize > array.length) {       return [array];     }      const subarrays: T[][] = [];     for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += chunkSize) {       const subarray = array.slice(i, i + chunkSize);       subarrays.push(subarray);     }     return subarrays;   };    const subArrays = divideArray(littleAnimals, 4);   return (     <div className='w-full h-full flex items-center flex-col overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-auto min-h-screen bg-white'>       <HeaderAnimals />       <div         ref={emblaRef}         className='overflow-hidden block sm:h-auto'         style={{ height: '100%', overflowY: 'scroll' }}       >         <div           className='carousel-container'           style={{             backfaceVisibility: 'hidden',             display: 'flex',             touchAction: 'pan-Y',             flexDirection: 'column',             height: '100%',             justifyContent: 'center',           }}         >          {subArrays.map((lotteryGroup, groupIndex) => (             <div               key={groupIndex}               className='flex flex-col md:gap-10 py-5 items-center justify-center '               style={{                 flex: '0 0 100%',                 minHeight: 0,               }}             >               {lotteryGroup.map(loteria => {                 return (                   <div key={loteria.name} className='w-full'>                       <div className=''/>                       <Cards image={loteria.image || ''} items={loteria.items} name={loteria.name} />                   </div>                 );               })}             </div>           ))}         </div>       </div>       </div>   ); };  export default LittleAnimals;
```

and my component is

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { LazyLoadImage } from 'react-lazy-load-image-component';
import 'react-lazy-load-image-component/src/effects/blur.css';
import { Skeleton } from '@nextui-org/skeleton';

type CardsProps = {
  image: string;
  name: string;
  items: {
    appointment: string;
    result: number;
    image: string;
    animal: string;
  }[];
};

export function Cards({ image, name, items }: CardsProps) {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState<boolean[]>(new Array(items.length).fill(false));
  const [showSkeleton, setShowSkeleton] = useState<boolean[]>(new Array(items.length).fill(true));

  const handleLoad = (index: number) => {
    const newLoaded = [...loaded];
    newLoaded[index] = true;
    setLoaded(newLoaded);

    setTimeout(() => {
      const newShowSkeleton = [...showSkeleton];
      newShowSkeleton[index] = false;
      setShowSkeleton(newShowSkeleton);
    }, 2000); // 2 seconds delay
  };
  return (
    <div className='w-full px-7 bg-custom-white border-custom-black border-solid border-8 rounded-[2.5rem] 3xl:rounded-[3rem] 4xl:rounded-[3.5rem] 5xl:rounded-[4rem] '>
      {/* Para dispositivos móviles */}
      <div className='md:hidden gap-y-15'>
        {/* Título de la lotería */}
        <div className='flex justify-center text-center mb-2'>
          <img src={image} alt={name} className='w-full h-auto' />
        </div>
        {/* Sorteos */}
        <div className='grid grid-cols-3 gap-2'>
          {items.map((item, index) => (
            <div key={index} className='flex flex-col justify-center mb-2 h-auto'>
              <div>
                <p className='text-center text-xl font-black text-custom-blue'>{item.appointment}</p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <LazyLoadImage
                  className='w-full p-2 justify-center align-middle place-content-center'
                  src={item.image} 
                  alt={item.animal}
                  effect='blur'
                  placeholder={showSkeleton[index] ? <Skeleton className='rounded-lg' /> : undefined}
                  afterLoad={() => handleLoad(index)}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
      {/* Para pantallas md o superiores */}
      <div className='hidden md:block  mb-2 h-auto'>
        <div
          className='grid grid-cols-1 place-items-center gap-4 sm:grid-cols-12 sm:gap-4 md:grid-cols-12 md:gap-2
   lg:gap-10 items-center'
        >
          {/* Título de la lotería */}
          <div className='col-span-12 sm:col-span-2 md:col-span-1 lg:col-span-1 flex justify-center'>
            <img src={image} alt={name} className='w-full object-cover object-center' />
          </div>
          {/* Sorteos */}
          {items.map((item, index) => (
            <div
              key={index}
              className='col-span-4 sm:col-span-1 md:col-span-1 lg:col-span-1 flex flex-col justify-center items-center relative h-auto'
            >
              <div>
                <p className='text-xl text-custom-blue font-black'>{item.appointment}</p>
              </div>
             
              {!loaded[index] && <Skeleton className='rounded-lg' />}
              <div className=''>
                <LazyLoadImage
                  className='w-full justify-center align-middle place-content-center'
                  src={item.image}
                  alt={item.animal}
                  effect='blur'
                  placeholder={showSkeleton[index] ? <Skeleton className='rounded-lg' /> : undefined}
                  afterLoad={() => handleLoad(index)}
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <p className='text-xl text-custom-blue font-black mt-[-15px]'>{item.animal}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```